# How to conserve the integrity of the string from a database response using Python

Tags: python, postgresql, unicode, python-3.x

i am using py-postgresql as the driver the database, when make a select to a string with non-ASCII characters, the response replace the character with "�" what can i make to change this to the correct character?

This is my code:

```
class decodify:

    def __init__(self):
        db = pgDriver.connect(user = 'demo', password='demo' database='hidura_karinapp', host='localhost', port='5432')
        d = db.prepare("""SELECT modules_reg.code FROM modules_reg, domain_reg, sbdomain_reg, sbdomdl_asc where(modules_reg.id = sbdomdl_asc.module AND modules_reg.mdname = 'police' AND sbdomain_reg.id = sbdomdl_asc.domain AND sbdomain_reg.domain = domain_reg.id AND domain_reg.dname = 'bmsuite.com' AND sbdomain_reg.sbname = 'www')""")
        s = d()
        print(s)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    decodify()
```

Comment: Ppl thanks for everything, the problem was on the JS that handles the data and send it to the server now i have to fixed there, but thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you setting a `client_encoding` ? In theory py-postgresql should use the correct `client_encoding` automatically. Either you are setting it to something wrong, or there is something wrong on how it detects it, in which case you have to set it. The question is then to what. :)

Comment: On Postgresql the client_encodig is utf8, i didn't change the client_encoding on the postgres

Answer (score 0):

What character encoding are you using in the database? Check the client_encoding setting in your postgresql.conf file, and see if that's utf-8 as well.

Comment: Yes it is, using the utf-8 enconding because the db support the character the driver not.

Answer (score 0):

What I do is a trick to set the Python default encoding to the same as the database encoding. My database is UTF-8, so I have to start top-level scripts like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python -S

import sys
sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8")
import site
```

The all the strings come across clean, without translation. That's with Python 2.x. Python 3 may be different.

Comment: That doesn' t work, <samp>import sys
sys.setdefaultencoding("utf8")
import site
</samp>
And give me this:AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'setdefaultencoding'

Comment: @hidura Are you using Python 3?

Comment: Yes, but i solve it, the problem doesn't was on the Python it was on the Javascript, but thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

You could use psycopg2, which supports unicode...

Comment: But it's Python 3 support is in beta and has only been out for a couple of weeks, maybe the project started before that?

Comment: I preffer use py-postgresql this was the only problem with this driver.